# How to link css file in node.js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to node.js and js in general. I have a simple app that have a styles.css but I dont know how to link it on the app.js.

In the `index.html` it has `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">`

And this is my app.js for the node.js:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;


fs.readFile('index.html', (err, html) =>{
    if (err){
        throw err;
    }
    const server = http.createServer((req,res) => {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/html');
        res.write(html);
        res.end();

    });

    server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
        console.log('Server started on port ' + port);
    });
});
```

So how should I modify `app.js` so that it will be able to locate the css file?

Comment: Your request handler always responds with the contents of your `index.html`. So when the browser parses the html, it then requests `css/styles.css` which your server responds by sending it the `index.html` again. You should distinguish between requests for `index.html` and `css/styles.css` to return content accordingly.

Comment: import "path to CSS file";

Comment: Are you familiar with Express.js or is it a requirement to use raw Node.js without any frameworks?

Answer (score 1):

for every request you are returning index.html.

Try this:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;


fs.readFile('index.html', (err, html) =>{
    if (err){
        throw err;
    }
    const server = http.createServer((req,res) => {


        res.statusCode = 200;
        if(req.url == '/'){
        res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/html');
        res.write(html);
        res.end();
        res.statusCode = 200;
        } 

        else if(req.url == '/css/styles.css'){
            res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/css');
            res.write(fs.readFileSync('css/styles.css'));
            res.end();
        } else {
            res.write("invalid request")
            res.end();
        }

    });

    server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
        console.log('Server started on port ' + port);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not limited to raw `node.js` and can use `express.js` here is what you can do to serve static files

Here is your server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Your app is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Then you create a folder and call it public and that's where all your client-side goes...

Here is an live demo for a complete working example: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/peridot-wildcat?path=README.md:1:0